# PowerDesigner 16.5 - Can't create new or update existing models

Tags: powerdesigner

I am using SAP/Sybase PowerDesigner 16.5.  Have used it on and off for years.
Whilst I haven't opened it for a few months, I suddenly find I cannot update an existing model (I can open it OK); Nor can I create a new Model (PDM or LDM - and probably nothing else either)
 I have tried both opening a blank workspace, and create a new model; and open an existing model.
In simple terms, it appears like I am reduced to read-only status.

My question is this: Is this a known issue, and how to resolve?

I am running 64bit Windows 7 Professional (v6.1 SP1) and Office 2010 - neither has changed although we download and install regular Windows updates.We have not downloaded any updates to PowerDesigner since downloading and installing 16.5 about May last year.
I have tried uninstalling PowerDesigner and re-installing.

Comment: Any message in the Output window? `Help>About PowerDesigner` should show the license in the middle of the dialog window, between the `Version`, and the copyright lines. Do you have something relevant in the `Tools>License Parameters` dialog?

Comment: No message in the output window.  
No reference to license in 'About PowerDesigner' window. (we are definitely licensed; I have uninstalled and reinstalled 16.5, and it should allow reinstall without a license, although it did not ask me to point to the license file). 
And no 'Tools>license tab.

Comment: Downloaded and installed SP5.  Issue resolved itself.
In installing, I had the opportunity to re-enter license details (which I did).  This is the only thing I can think of that might have 'fixed it'. 
Am back in business.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to give a follow-up.